# HTTP Response 401 while trying to subscribe Outlook Events - Java

Tags: java, outlook, outlook-restapi

I am using Outlook Rest API to subscribe events. However, I get error code 401 although I include the access token. I get the access token following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/java-tutorial this tutorial. And my payload is like the following:

{

"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",

"Resource":"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events",

"NotificationURL":URL,

"ChangeType":"Created"

}

with the header:

authorization: Bearer + access token which I get from the tutorial. (I.E EwBAA8l6BAAURSN/FHlDW5xN74t6GzbtsBBeBUYAAeybQmu+RnQcYAQ3wTW3kJUclA03jKgc4Sdx2mp5SOlLswSAr9zTmO7qk33wpTD3ULZkUrl9IpTnnhtjeoSXt+z5GRRtmL40jyvAghrTseO8yEZtR04SLjl6i1KZNXxZwUTK8s6DkXESwkwaTmQKPckKHi9XeIbx8dolnT7vEeeUo5rmzcG251dQokfZYHCar3bd1bysV7oaTt5Iis6qgkYtg4BL/32QObgI8SHQS4my7FSsqLYFchYExEFeBXgUjt4yE0G0bbmykz3T5C713DAqo8BtCkkbRIckv6N4bpq84bpzaDAgdgHhnpcYzUaViJ2zhZXMrShUdpddug+DPkEDZgAACILe9sz+3mX7EAJrVvnkVpyZzC9WvQkY4xET3KdEstT..... Something like this)

content-type: application/json

Why do I get 401?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 401 means that your token isn't valid for what you're trying to do. It could be expired, invalid, etc. Typically the body of the response gives more detail on the reason of the 401.

I'd recommend going to https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/ and playing with the notifications API there to see how it all works.

Comment: The body says Unauthorized. I do not understand why the token is not valid because I am trying to subscribe as soon as I log in. The token is like 3 or 4 minutes old.

Comment: I think I 've just found the problem. I am using graph API to login, and outlook API to register push notifications.. However, when I change it to graph url now I get bad request.

Comment: Yes that would be a problem. The payload for Graph is slightly different, see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscription_post_subscriptions